# Program doesn't run all the way through

Tags: java, compilation

So I'm trying to write a program for my computer programming class, it's supposed to print out a calendar for the month. I want my program to come up with the first day of the month without asking the person for the starting day, so I found an equation that'll do that and tried to use it in the program. It compiles fine, but when it reaches the part where it should start the equation and print out the calendar, the program just...stops. It stops running entirely and returns to the V:\JavaPrograms> command prompt thing.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lesson13p2_ThuotteEmily
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
   Scanner r=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("What year is it? ");
   int y=r.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Please pick a month from the list below:");
   System.out.println("\n1. January\n2. February\n3. March");

   Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter your choice here by inputting the number next to the month: ");
   int m=b.nextInt();

   int d=1, o;

   switch(m)
   {
     case 1:
       o=13;
       int n=d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2;

       if(n==1)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Sunday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==2)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Monday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==3)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Tuesday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==4)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Wednesday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==5)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Thursday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==6)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Friday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
       else if(n==7)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for January, "+y+", which starts on a Saturday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tJanuary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
          while(j<=4)
          {
            for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
            {
              System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
          ++j;
       }
     case 2:       
       if((y%100!=0||y%400==0)&&y%4==0)
       {
         o=14;
         int n=d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2;
         if(n==1)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Sunday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==2)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Monday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==3)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Tuesday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==4)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Wednesday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==5)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Thursday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==6)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Friday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==7)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Saturday and is a leap year.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=29;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
       }
       else
       {
         o=14;
         int n=d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2;

         if(n==1)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Sunday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==2)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Monday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==3)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Tuesday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==4)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Wednesday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==5)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Thursday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==6)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Friday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
         else if(n==7)
         {
           System.out.println("Here is your calendar for February, "+y+", which starts on a Saturday.");
           System.out.println("\t\tFebruary\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           int j = 0, k=0;
           while(j<=4)
           {
             for(k=1;k<=28;k++)
             {
               System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
             }
             System.out.println("");
           }
           ++j;
         }
       }
     case 3:
       o=3;
       int n=d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2;

       if(n==1)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Sunday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==2)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Monday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==3)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Tuesday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
         for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==4)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Wednesday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==5)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Thursday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==6)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Friday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
       else if(n==7)
       {
         System.out.println("Here is your calendar for March, "+y+", which starts on a Saturday.");
         System.out.println("\t\tMarch\nSun\tMon\tTues\tWed\tThurs\tFri\tSat\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         int j = 0, k=0;
         while(j<=4)
         {
           for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
           {
             System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
           }
           System.out.println("");
         }
         ++j;
       }
   }
 }
}
```

Also, I tried using just a regular if statement first, but it didn't work.

Comment: Print out the value of `m` and `n`

Comment: you really should replace the body of your if's with a method

Comment: I strongly recommend that you learn to use a debugger.  It would tell you immediately what is happening.

Comment: What do you see when you try to debug your program using your debugger? I suggest you step through your program to see what it is doing and why.

Comment: Thank goodness this doesn't go all the way to December!

Comment: Question. What is a debugger and what do I do to get one? I don't have one of those, my computer programming teacher never even mentioned them...

Comment: And a debugger lets you run line by line, looking at what each variable currently is

Comment: *"Question. What is a debugger and what do I do to get one? I don't have one of those, my computer programming teacher never even mentioned them..."* This is the problem with "Computer Science" teachers, they still 30 years later don't teach anything fundamentally practical to beginners. First thing to teach is what a version control system is and how to use it, second thing to teach is how to use a step debugger, then you learn how to compile/link your code and run it. Your teacher is incompetent!

Comment: Not teaching what a *step debugger* is before how to compile and run your program is like teaching someone to drive and only explaining the accelerator pedal, and never mentioning the brake or clutch pedal!

Comment: To be honest, if I were the teacher, I would have introduced using sensible variable names by now.  Who knows what `j, k, m, n, o` are all supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for n is incorrect

```
n=d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2;
```

A year of 2009 will give an n of at least 2009. In fact the n is more like 2533 for january 2009. You only have conditions for n between 1 and 7, so its not suprising that an n of 2533 doesn't do anything. I suspect you may want

```
n=(d+2*o+(3*(o+1)/5)+y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)+2)%7;
```

Possible with a +1 at the end as you are using day numbers 1-7 not 0-6

#### Other comments.

You seem to repeat the same code over and over again. These should be extracted into seperate functions and called when needed. This will make your code easier to read and easier to maintain (as well as much much shorter.

For example the following is repeated a lot!

```
     int j = 0, k=0;
      while(j<=4)
      {
        for(k=1;k<=31;k++)
        {
          System.out.print((++j)+"\t\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
      }
      ++j;
```

Answer (score -1):

probably what is happening is you aren't reading in the value properly from the command line (System.in) thereby having an int which doesn't give an expected value in the switch and just bypasses all of your calendar logic. Make certain that you are reading the correct value in. The way you can test this if you're not using a debugger is to hard code an expected integer value like the integer "1" and use that value instead of the one that you are reading in from the command line. The fact that your program is returning the command prompt suggests that the program is return from main and not stopping. If the program were hanging in an infinite while loop for example it would give the appearance of hanging but you'd never get back to the command prompt. Hope this helps.